# When it's a right time to -expandItem: in a NSOutlineView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appkit, nsoutlineview

I have an NSOutlineView that I use to display some items grouped by sections.

```
┌──────────────────────────────┐
│ Section 0                    │
└──────────────────────────────┘
  ┌────────────────────────────┐
  │ Item 0                     │
  └────────────────────────────┘
  ┌────────────────────────────┐
  │ Item 1                     │
  └────────────────────────────┘
┌──────────────────────────────┐
│ Section 1                    │
└──────────────────────────────┘
  ┌────────────────────────────┐
  │ Item 2                     │
  └────────────────────────────┘
```

Outline view is backed by a custom fetched results controller that issues two kinds of notifications on model changes:

- **insert/move/delete section at index (to index)**
  When I get this notification I insert/move/delete an item at the root level of my outline view.
- **insert/update/move/delete item at index in section (to index in section)**
  When I get this notification I insert/update/move/delete an item at the corresponding section level.

That is, I manage outline view in an incremental fashion and didn't make a single -reloadData call.

Everything works as expected. **The sole problem is that I need my sections to always appear expanded**.

Unfortunately, `NSOutlineView` API doesn't allow you to insert an item in an expanded state from the very beginning. And there is no obvious way to customize this behaviour via subclassing (I used Hopper disassembler to learn about NSOutlineView internals, so correct me if I am wrong).

My first attempt was to call an `-expandItem:` just after I insert my section, but this doesn't have any effect at all.

The second attempt was to call an `-expandItem:` just before I add the first nested item to the simulated section. This has a side effect of double insert.

The only workaround that I found is to delay the `-expandItem:` call like this:

```
id section = ...

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
{
  [self.outlineView expandItem: section];
});
```

This feels really ugly and doesn't solve the problem completely. For example, sometimes more than one section is being added in one batch. Sometimes an item moves from some existing section to a new one, created especially for it and I want row movement animation to happen. Instead I get a slightly corrupted NSOutlineView layout, where my section row gets clipped after the section is populated for the first time via `-insertItemsAtIndexes:inParent:withAnimation:`. This run loop trick ruins everything.

**So the question is, when it is a right time to expand the item, inserted via `-insertItemsAtIndexes:inParent:withAnimation:`?**

Comment: Does it work fine while inserting items with no animation?

Comment: @Astoria Unfortunately, no. Neither disabling an item insertion/movement/removal animations, nor disabling item expansion animation fixes the issue.

Comment: Could you provide more code where you insert an item. Do you use `beginUpdates`?